# AutoMapper from DTO to Entity Framework with nested collection

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, dto

I have this model:

[image]

And I want to add a new Autor like below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            AutorServiceClient service = new AutorServiceClient();

            LivroContract[] livros = {
                new LivroContract { id_tipo = 1, nome_livro = "Asp.Net MVC 5" },
                new LivroContract { id_tipo = 1, nome_livro = "Asp.Net Entity Framework" }
            };

            AutorContract autorContract = new AutorContract()
            {
                nome_autor = "Novo Autor",
                Livros = livros
            };

            if (service.Add(autorContract))
                Console.WriteLine("Adicionado com Sucesso");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Erro !!!");
        }
    }
}
```

My Autor class has a nested Livro collection and I want to insert a new Autor with its respective Livro entities.

Below is part of my Data Access code to make the insert:

```
    public class AutorDA
    {
        private readonly BibliotecaEntities _context;
        private readonly DbSet<Autor> _dbSet;

        public AutorDA()
        {
            _context = new BibliotecaEntities();
            _dbSet = _context.Set<Autor>();

            Mapping();
        }

        public void Mapping()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Autor, AutorDTO>();
                cfg.CreateMap<AutorDTO, Autor>();
                cfg.CreateMap<ICollection<Autor>, IEnumerable<AutorDTO>>();
                cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<AutorDTO>, ICollection<Autor>>();

                cfg.CreateMap<Biblioteca, BibliotecaDTO>();
                cfg.CreateMap<BibliotecaDTO, Biblioteca>();
                cfg.CreateMap<ICollection<Biblioteca>, IEnumerable<BibliotecaDTO>>();
                cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<BibliotecaDTO>, ICollection<Biblioteca>>();

                cfg.CreateMap<Livro, LivroDTO>();
                cfg.CreateMap<LivroDTO, Livro>();
                cfg.CreateMap<ICollection<Livro>, IEnumerable<LivroDTO>>();
                cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<LivroDTO>, ICollection<Livro>>();

                cfg.CreateMap<Tipo_Livro, TipoLivroDTO>();
                cfg.CreateMap<TipoLivroDTO, Tipo_Livro>();
                cfg.CreateMap<ICollection<Tipo_Livro>, IEnumerable<TipoLivroDTO>>();
                cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<TipoLivroDTO>, ICollection<Tipo_Livro>>();
            });
        }

        public bool Add(AutorDTO dto)
        {
            try
            {
                Mapping();

                Autor autor = Mapper.Map<Autor>(dto);

                _dbSet.Add(autor);

                _context.SaveChanges();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
....
```

Here is my DTOs:

```
public class AutorDTO
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nome_autor { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LivroDTO> Livros { get; set; }
}

public class LivroDTO
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int id_tipo { get; set; }
    public string nome_livro { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AutorDTO> Autores { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BibliotecaDTO> Bibliotecas { get; set; }
    public TipoLivroDTO TipoLivro { get; set; }
}
```

I know that there is something wrong here, but I dont know what... I am trying to insert Autor and a couple of Livros entities, but I dont know how to do that, using AutoMapper and EF.

But with this code, I am only inserting Autor.

So, I have two situations I dont know how to do:

- Insert a new Autor and new Livro entities
- Insert a new Autor and associate it with already inserted Livro entities

How I configure AutoMapper to those two situations above ?

Finally, my last questions are:

- What is the better approach for situations where we have a main entity, which has one or more child entities (1:n / n:n) ?
- Is it a good idea to insert/update simultanneosly all those entities, or it is a bad idea ? If it is a bad idea, so what is best way to do insert a main class and its relations ?
- As we can see, my Livro entity has other child relations, but I want to use only Autor and Livro. I need to map all model/entities just to use those two ones ?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of this `cfg.CreateMap<Autor, AutorDTO>();cfg.CreateMap<AutorDTO, Autor>();`  you can cfg.CreateMap<Autor, AutorDTO>.ReverseMap(). it will do the reverse mapping

Comment: You can find the nested mapping here https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Nested-mappings. I think your entities will mapped automatically as complex type are default mapped by automapper.

Comment: @Eldho But my nested properties are collections... this example you said I have seem but I am still not having my child collection being saved. About my other questions... Is it a bad practice do insert and updates in main class and its child relations ?

Comment: Did u check is it mapped or not ? I think ur entities have correctly mapped. Saving is related to EF , that another problem